# running JUNIT tests for automation build - how?

Tags: android, maven, ant, junit, gradle

I am new to automation. I have been working this [android tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-unit-testing-with-the-junit-testing-framework--mobile-421) for JUNIT. I ran it and it worked great - I was able to see results of my tests in the Eclipse IDE. The results display nicely on a gui screen. But, how can I see these results using automation build tools like gradle , maven , or ant? I would like to see these JUNIT test results OUTSIDE of the IDE so that anyone can just press a button and the project would compile and see the JUNIT results ...

I tried to look through many documents but could to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle run this command:

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```

The regular gradle build task does not include the connected checks. Connected checks are the unit tests being run on connected devices. So you'll need to have an actual device or emulator running at the time of the command.

Answer (score 0):

For Ant :

1)If your Emulator is running, open Command Prompt and 
navigate to your Test Project directory

2)run the following command:

command: adb shell am instrument -w com.yourtestpackage/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

You can see the Test Results.